# Send batch users their usernames via email using PHP

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I am trying to write some PHP code that emails every user in my database (around 500) their usernames. I have successfully managed to pull the email addresses and usernames for each user and store them in an array. However, I cannot figure out how to email each individual user with their individual usernames. I am pretty sure I need to use a `foreach` loop to do this, but I have had no luck.
Here is what I have.

```
<?php
include('databaseConn.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff");
$emailArray;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$emailArray[] = array($row['email']=>$row['username']);
}

print_r($emailArray); //This associative array now contains each username along with their respective email address.

?>
```

==***********************===
WITH MAIL FUNCTION

```
<?php
include('functions/core.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$emailArray;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $emailArray[] = array($row['email']=>$row['username']);
}

foreach($emailArray as $email => $username) {
    echo $username; // outputs the indexes.


$subject = 'Accoutn Details';

$message = 'This email contains your login details.<br/><br/>
<b>Username: '.$username.'</b><br/>
<br/><br/>Kind regards,<br/>';

$headers = 'From: noreply@xxxxx.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@xxxxx.co.uk' . "\r\n" .

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

mail($emailAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);

}


//print_r($emailArray);

?>
```

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)).

Comment: why not send the mail in the while loop, no need to lop twice. 500 at a time could be an issue if you are on a shared host.

Comment: There's several examples in the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bad idea to use mail in a loop unless its a one off, which it sounds like it, also most shared hosts would not allow 500 emails to be sent at once.

```
$subject = 'Account Details';
$headers = 'From: noreply@xxxxx.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@xxxxx.co.uk' . "\r\n" .

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$message = 'This email contains your login details.<br/><br/>
<b>Username: '.$row['username'].'</b><br/>
<br/><br/>Kind regards,<br/>';

mail("$row['email']", $subject, $message, $headers);

    }
```

Comment: Wow, so simple yet exactly what I needed. Thanks for taking the time out and answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to use foreach... http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

For example:

```
foreach ($emailArray as $email => $username) {
    // Send an email to $email with their $username
}
```

@Dagon is right, there's no need to iterate twice if there's nothing else you need the associative array for. Even if you do need an array, it doesn't necessarily have to be associative; it could be the raw rows from the DB, which you could iterate over. The only time you *need* an associative array is when you need to look up the values (usernames) by the keys (email addresses), which, as far as I can tell, you don't need to do.